# Why is BIND DNS zone transfer update not displaying on terminal screen but showing in logs as up to date?

Tags: centos, dns

I have configured a master/Slave zone, the zone transfer happens but does not display on the terminal screen, on the terminal screen it shows notifies ONLY, but when I check the /var/log/named the zone is up to date, is there a setting for it to display on screen.

**MASTER NAMED.CONF FILE**

```
acl internals { 192.168.102.0/24; };
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.102.191; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-transfer { 192.168.102.192; };
        allow-query     { localhost; internals; };
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "L00144445.local" { type master; file "L00144445.db"; allow-transfer { 192.168.102.192; }; notify yes; };

zone "102.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" { type master; file "54444100L.db"; allow-transfer { 192.168.102.192; }; notify yes; };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

**FORWARD LOOKUP FILE**

```
$TTL 10
$ORIGIN L00144445.local.
@       IN SOA ns1.L00144445.local. admin.L00144445.local. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        10      ; refresh
                                        10      ; retry
                                        10      ; expire
                                        10 )    ; minimum
        IN NS ns1.L00144445.local.
        IN NS ns2.L00144445.local.
ns1     IN A 192.168.102.191
ns2     IN A 192.168.102.192
```

**REVERSE LOOKUP FILE**

```
$TTL 10
$ORIGIN 102.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.
@       IN SOA ns1.L00144445.local. admin.L00144445.local. (
                                        0              ; serial
                                        10      ; refresh
                                        10      ; retry
                                        10      ; expire
                                        10 )    ; minimum
        IN NS ns1.L00144445.local.
        IN NS ns2.L00144445.local.
191     IN PTR ns1.L00144445.local.
192     IN PTR ns2.L00144445.local.
```

**SLAVE NAMED.CONF FILE**

```
acl internals { 192.168.102.0/24; };
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.102.192; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-notify { 192.168.102.191; };
        allow-query { localhost; internals; };
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "L00144445.local" { type slave; masters { 192.168.102.191; }; file "L00144445.db";};

zone "102.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA" { type slave; masters { 192.168.102.191; }; file "54444100L.db"; allow-transfer { 192.168.102.191; }; notify yes; };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

[image]

Comment: What's in your picture? It's illegible here on my phone.

Comment: Sorry, justbthe last 3 lines in both the terminal windows matter, since the right windows says ZONE UP TO DATE, while the left window still shows SENDING NOTIFIES

Comment: Ditto, illegible in my phone. Please avoid posting text as images.

Comment: Avoid using TLD `.local` as it will clash with mDNS.

Comment: What do you mean by "displaying on screen"? In your configuration, you are specifically logging to a file, so everything that counts should be in that file.